# setting default tab in tabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have tried this:

```
class MainVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

       self.selectedIndex = 3

    }

}
```

But all it does it takes me to a blank view.  The tab bar is highlighted at the bottom.

I am trying to set the default tab when the app starts.

Comment: don't forget to add `super.viewDidAppear(true)`

Comment: Wow. Good catch. Thanks

Comment: was that the only issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

> The order in which you specify the view controllers determines the order in which they appear in the tab bar. When setting this property, you should also assign a value to the `selectedViewController` property to indicate which view controller is selected initially.